# The kernel of a ring homomorphism is not necessarily a maximal ideal

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, field-theory

Let $\phi$: $R \mapsto k$ where $k$ is a field be a ring homomorphism.

I am trying to find an example where $ker(\phi)$ is not a maximal ideal of $R$

I would appreciate any hints or help, thanks!

Comment: $\mathbb Z \rightarrow \mathbb Q$ inclusion map

Comment: A nontrivial example: consider the evaluation map $\Bbb Z[X] \to \Bbb Q$ defined by $f(X) \mapsto f(1)$.

Comment: If $\phi:R\to k$ is onto, then $R/\ker(\phi)\cong k$. So, you need a non-onto homomorphism.

Answer (score 0):

Since $R/\ker\phi\cong\operatorname{im}\phi$, you have that

> $\ker\phi$ is maximal if and only if $\operatorname{im}\phi$ is a subfield of $k$.

Can you think to a homomorphism where the image is not a subfield? Of course $R$ must not be a field itself.